# Trying to implement login with Codeigniter/MVC ... expecting TRUE, receiving FALSE. Why?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, codeigniter

i'm trying to implement a Facebook login procedure and it's not working.  I have a POST to AJAX that seems to be interpreting a returned TRUE incorrectly. And although I've put logs throughout to track the logic flow.. it doesn't seem to be flowing like I expect it.  Can you see the problem?

Here is my .js that POSTS to AJAX

```
function initUserFbConnect(response){
    console.log("initUserFacebookConnect");
    // checking if the user is in the DB or first visit
    $.post('../ajax/checkFbMember', { facebookId: response.id },
        function(data){
            if(data){
                console.log("trying to set login time");
                $.post('../ajax/setLoginTime', { facebookId:response.id },
                    function(data2){
                        if(data2 == true){
                            console.log("Login time logged");
                        }else{
                            console.log("problem logging time");
                        }
                    }
                );
            }else{
                console.log("returned false from AJAX post");
                console.log(data);
                console.log("you are NOT a FB member");
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And here is ../ajax/checkFbMember

```
public function checkFbMember()
{
    $facebookId = $this->input->post('facebookId');
    ChromePhp::log("checking checkFBmember " . $facebookId  );
    $this->load->model('Member_model');
    if( $this->Member_model->mCheckFbMember( $facebookId )){
        ChromePhp::log('FB id found in system');
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        ChromePhp::log('FB id NOT found in system');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and here is my Member_model

```
public function mCheckFbMember( $facebookId )
{
    ChromePhp::log('Inside model and checking');
    $_query = $this->db->query( "SELECT users.id FROM users WHERE users.facebookID=$facebookId" );
    if ( $_query->num_rows() > 0 ){ // user is found
        ChromePhp::log('Inside model and FOUND member');
        return TRUE;
    }else{ // means first visit
        ChromePhp::log('Inside model FAIL');
        return FALSE;  
    }
}
```

But this is what i am logging .. the order is weird

```
initUserFacebookConnect
returned false from AJAX post  // << this seems to come too early!
// console.log(data) doesn't log anything .. why?
you are NOT a FB member
checking checkFBmember 657322189
Inside model and checking 
Inside model and FOUND member
FB id found in system
```

So I am posting to ajax .. I am hitting my model and returning TRUE to my controller which returns TRUE back to initUserFbConnect .. but somehow that POST method receiving FALSE?  More than that.. it skips right ahead and shows me "returned false" *before* any of my other methods fire?

I'm confused why I'm returning FALSE since I'm finding the member in the DB.. but I'm also confused of the order that my logging is firing.  I expect the IF statement in initUserFbConnect to resolve *after* everything else has returned to it.  But it seems to be jumping the gun.  It has to go through the PHP and DB check first to even *know* that it has received a TRUE/FALSE, right?

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is nothing coming back in the response.

From just the code you posted, you're returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` from the functions, but the JavaScript will only read text that has been `echo`'d from the page.

The simplest solution is to `echo` `"TRUE"` or `"FALSE"` based on the return value from `checkFbMember()` and then change your ajax parsing to be:

```
if (data2 == "TRUE") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok..  I didn't realize that JS wouldn't interpret true/false.  I will echo instead.  Thanks for the help!  But still.. shouldn't the other logs fire before "returned FALSE from AJAX post"?  Doesnt it need to go through all the other stuff before it knows what it has got back in the first place?  ( edit - I've echoed now.. and it works.. but I still have the weird logging order)